# Difference between .items() and .keys()

Tags: python

Is there any advantage to using the first block of code over the second one when iterating over a dictionary?

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if v == None:
        mydict[k] = ''
```

and

```
for k in mydict.keys():
    if mydict[k] == None:
        mydict[k] = ''
```

Comment: In any case, note that `if ... is None:` is recommended.

Comment: As a note the word *code* doesn't make sense alone here (*codes* especially sounds odd), a better phrasing might be *which block of code is better?*. Code is, in itself, plural - much like water. It doesn't make sense to talk about many *waters* or a *water*, rather we refer to a *body of water* or many *bodies*. (Not trying to be all grammar nazi here, just I see this a lot, so thought I'd give a bit of advice).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first method is arguably clearer and easier to read, so I would always recommend it over the latter.

That said, in a simple case like this, the better option would be a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
{k: v if v is not None else "" for k, v in mydict.items()}
```

It's worth a note that the second example can be simplified, as iterating directly over `mydict` will provide the keys, so no need for `mydict.keys()` (which is mainly useful for when you want the set of keys for another purpose, not iteration).

(As jathanism notes in the comments, in older versions of Python (2.x), using `iteritems()` is a better option than `items()` as it does not produce a list - 3.x users like myself don't need to worry as `items()` produces a dictionary view, which is lazy.)

Comment: My only suggestion would be to use `.iteritems()` when iterating a dictionary in this fashion.

Comment: @jathanism Only in 2.x though.

Comment: Good point, I always forget about 2.x quirks these days. Added.

Comment: `dictionary comprehension` is not available until 2.7.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic As dictionary comprehensions are just syntactic sugar for `dict(...)` where `...` is a generator expression giving `key, value` pairs, it's trivial to convert for pre-2.7 - in this case: `dict((k, v if v is not None else "") for k, v in mydict.iteritems())`.